# PostgreSQL problem with the "Group By" Clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table that looks something like this when `ORDERED by R_Value Desc`
Note that it is important to understand that the below table is SQL `SELECT ordered by R_Value`

```
Id   Letter   R_Value
1     A         1500
2     A         1400
4     B         800
9     B         700
10    B         600
11    A         400
12    A         200
```

I want my result set to look like this.  The result set needs to be grouped 3
times. Each time, the letter changes from A to B or vice versa, a new group should
be formed.

```
Letter     Max_RValue
A           1500
B            800
A            400
```

I have already experimented with various things- lead/lag functions, partitioning, etc. and it seems impossible. A simple `Group by(Letter)` obviously won't work because
all 'A' will be put in one group which is not what I want.

My next step would be to try this in a procedural language, dump it in an
intermediate table and then read the results. Before doing that, is this even
possible in Ordinary SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LAG()` window function to check the previous value of `Letter` for each row and `SUM()` window function to create the groups of rows of consecutive occurrences.

Then aggregate in each group:

```
SELECT Letter, MAX(R_Value) Max_RValue
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(flag::int) OVER (ORDER BY R_Value DESC) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, Letter <> LAG(Letter, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY R_Value DESC) flag
    FROM tablename
  ) t  
) t  
GROUP BY grp, Letter;
```

Or, simpler just select the rows where the `Letter` changes:

```
SELECT Letter, R_Value
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(Letter, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY R_Value DESC) prev_Letter
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE Letter <> prev_Letter;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=7d66fb52b56d86915ffe83827bb83dab).

Answer (score 0):

Forpas's second solution is okay but it can be written more simply in Postgres as:

```
select letter, r_value
from (select t.*, lag(letter) over (order by r_value) as prev_letter
      from t
     ) t
where prev_letter is distinct from letter;
```